# ASP.NET: Using ContentPlaceHolders to Handle Authentication

Tags: asp.net, authentication, master-pages, contentplaceholder

I've got my own authentication system set up in my ASP.NET web app and I'm using ContentPlaceHolders to determine which content is shown to the user, depending on whether they are logged in and what their viewing privileges are. Right now, I have 3 ContentPlaceHolders all occupying the same  in my master page, all initially set to Visible="false"; one for logged out users, one for users that are logged in but have not been validated by an admin, and one for a logged in and validated user. My OnInit override in my masterpage codebehind makes calls to the database to determine which placeholder should be made visible.

I'm working under the assumption that since ContentPlaceHolder and Content (in content pages) are merged while the page is being fetched, and that any placeholders left invisible wont be merged with their associated Content controls from the content page.

I'm worried about the security of this system. Can i safely assume that  blocks in content pages will be entirely inaccessible to unauthenticated users if their associated placeholders are invisible at page initialization?

I'm basically using this to mimic the functionality of ASP.NET's built in authentication system, that hides and shows content through the use of AnonymousTemplate and LoggedInTemplate (before anyone suggests, i don't want to use ASP.NET's built in authentication).

Is there a better way to handle this or should my system work just fine?

Comment: It sounds like it works fine. If you set .visible = False to a server control, then it will not get rendered to the client. Bottom line is - test it. Try it with the different user types and see what the results are

Comment: im not worried about whether it will be rendered, strictly speaking. Im worried about whether the hidden content will still be technically accessible. For example, asp controls that are initially invisible can be set to visible by page events AFTER the pages have been fetched. This functionality could be considered a security vulnerability in my system if content blocks could be made to appear post-fetch through their "visible" properties.

Comment: Unless you set the visible property to true, then it will remain false. If this wan't the case, apps would be breaking all the time